# Query to locate a secret

Tags: azure-keyvault

I have hundreds of keyvaults and they are named like ABC-DEV-001, ABC-TEST-002, etc... At times, I need to locate a secret say `APIKey` in all of them. How can I query with the name of a secret and find the keyvault name? I wonder whether it is possible to use Resource Graph -

```
Resources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.keyvault/vaults'
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I query with the name of a secret and find the key vault name? I wonder whether it is possible to use Resource Graph

According to this, [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/683043/how-to-export-the-secrets-details-in-keyvaults-usi) the resource graph is used to querying the information at the resource level. so it is impossible to query with a secret name in the resource graph.

For work around you can use the KQL query to get the vault name in log analytics workspace.

**KQL query**

```
AzureDiagnostics
|where ResourceProvider =~ "MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT"
|where isAccessPolicyMatch_b == "true"
|where OperationName =="SecretGet"
|where id_s =="your id"
| limit 1
|project Resource, ResultType, CorrelationId
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure Key Vault logging | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/logging?tabs=Secrets#operation-names-table)